# How to modify line that is located one line after a specific line using Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file that contains the following lines:

```
...
# Check the date
date
...
```

I want to comment out the `date` command. But it occurses a few times in the file and I want to comment the `date` which is located right one line after the `# Check the date`, otherwise I would just use:

```
perl -i -pe 's:(.*date.*):#$1:' file
```

How can I improve my logic and comment out only the `date` right after the `# Check the date` comment?

Answer (score 4):

Remember whether the previous line was the comment in a variable:

```
perl -pe 's/^(date)$/#$1/ if $prev; $prev = /^# Check the date$/;'
```

Comment: Nit: I think you originally intended to assign the "previous" line to `$prev`, but changed your mind. As such, `$fix` makes a better variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wouldn't use `perl` for this in-place edit, I'd turn to good old `ed`:

```sh
printf '%s\n' '/^# Check the date/+1s/^/# /' w | ed -s file
```

will add a `#` to the beginning of the line following the first line that matches the regular expression `^# Check the date` and save the change.

```sh
printf '%s\n' '/^# Check the date/+1g/^date$/s/^/# /' w | ed -s file
```

will do the same only if the next line is `date`.